# Sendmail in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sendmail

I am developing a Matlab code to send mails through Microsoft outlook (code below). When I run the code, it shows no errors. However, the mail is not delivered to the recipient either.
Version - R2014a.
Is there any problem with the SMTP server address or SMTP port number?
I have taken the server address and port number from the IT admin. So, there should be no issue regarding those two things.
What should I do?

```
Setpref (‘Internet’,’E_mail’,’yourmailid@mailserver.com’);
Setpref (‘Internet’,’SMTP_Username’,’yourmailid@mailserver.com’);
Setpref (‘Internet’,’SMTP_Password’,’yourpassword’);
Setpref (‘Internet’,’SMTP_Server’,‘smtp-mail.mailserver.com’);
Props=java.lang.System.getproperties;
Props.setProperty (‘mail.smtp.auth’,’true’);
Props.setproperty(‘mail.smtp.socketFactory.class’,’javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.port’);
Props.setProperty(‘mail.smtp.socketFactory.port’,’25’);
Sendmail(‘recipientmailid@recipientserver.com’,’Mail from Matlab’,’your message body’);
```

Comment: Have you tried mailing yourself? (i.e. send from and to  `yourmailid@mailserver.com` ).  If that works then you know it's something on the recipient mail side.

Comment: Yes I have tried that too. But the problem remains the same. There is no error showing. However, there is no message in my inbox either.