# Running a matlab script by getting an email

Tags: matlab, hpc

Is there a way to run a matlab script by getting an email? What I'm trying to achieve is running a program on a hpc server when that work finishes it sends an email that it finished. When it finishes I want matlab to evaluate the data. 
Is there a way to do it? 
Thanks

Comment: I think there should be a way. Try googling ["trigger script by email reception"](https://www.google.de/?q=trigger+script+by+email+reception) or something similar (will depend on how you receive your emails). Basically you can trigger a script that 1) [runs a script file from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line), 2) send the e-mail afterwards, 3) call another Matlab script file for evaluation of the data. HTH

Comment: Additional comment: you could also send the email via Matlab, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266890/sendmail-in-matlab and others